# Using Mockito, map function of Observable is not being called

Tags: android, mockito, observable

I'm using Mockito framework to test a class that returns an `Observable` (see comments):

This is the my implementation class:

```
public class DataRepository implements AbstractRepository {

    private DataSource dataSource;
    private DataMapper dataMapper;

    // Constructor
    public DataRepository(DataSource dataSource, DataMapper dataMapper) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.dataMapper = dataMapper;
    }

    /**
    * The call to dataSource.getItem(int) returns
    * an Observable of type ItemResponse.
    * So, in the map I cast it to an object of type Item.
    **/
    public Observable<Item> getItem(int id) {
        return dataSource.getItem(id)
            .map(new Function<ItemResponse, Item>() {
                @Override
                public Item apply(ItemResponse itemResponse) throws Exception {
                    return dataMapper.transform(itemResponse);
                }
            });

    }
}
```

Now, this is my test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DataRepositoryTest {

    DataRepository dataRepository;

    @Mock
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Mock
    DataMapper dataMapper;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        dataRepository = new DataRepository(dataSource, dataMapper);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetItem() {
        // Given
        ItemResponse itemResponse = new ItemResponse();    
        given(dataSource.getItem(anyInt())).willReturn(Observable.just(itemResponse));

        // When
        dataRepository.getItem(anyInt());

        // Verify/then
        verify(dataSource).getItem(anyInt()); // This part runs fine.
        verify(dataMapper).transform(); // This is failing

    }

}
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
dataMapper.transform(
    com.my.package.ItemResponse@e720b71
);
-> at com.my.package.test.DataRepositoryTest.testGetItem(DataRepositoryTest.java:28)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

How can I tell Mockito to call the `map()` operator/method, then `apply()` of the `Observable` returned by `dataSource.getItem(int)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not subscribing the `Observable<Item>` returned by `public Observable<Item> getItem(int id)` so the `.map(...)` operator is not being called/executed, try with `dataRepository.getItem(anyInt()).subscribe();` just to verify.